# libgit2sharp-ssh working with proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy, libgit2sharp, libgit2sharp-ssh

I use the `libgit2sharp-ssh` and i implement the ssh connection successfully but now the `https/http` connection is not working under proxy ? 
i look at the implementation of the methods clone and Push in `libgit2sharp-ssh` lib and both of them the value of `ProxyOptions` is:

```
ProxyOptions = new GitProxyOptions { Version = 1 }  

   public virtual void Push(Remote remote, IEnumerable<string> pushRefSpecs, PushOptions pushOptions)
    {
        Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(remote, "remote");
        Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(pushRefSpecs, "pushRefSpecs");

        // Return early if there is nothing to push.
        if (!pushRefSpecs.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (pushOptions == null)
        {
            pushOptions = new PushOptions();
        }

        // Load the remote.
        using (RemoteHandle remoteHandle = Proxy.git_remote_lookup(repository.Handle, remote.Name, true))
        {
            var callbacks = new RemoteCallbacks(pushOptions);
            GitRemoteCallbacks gitCallbacks = callbacks.GenerateCallbacks();

            Proxy.git_remote_push(remoteHandle,
                                  pushRefSpecs,
                                  new GitPushOptions()
                                  {
                                      PackbuilderDegreeOfParallelism = pushOptions.PackbuilderDegreeOfParallelism,
                                      RemoteCallbacks = gitCallbacks,
                                      ProxyOptions = new GitProxyOptions { Version = 1 },
                                  });
        }
    }


internal enum GitProxyType
{
    None,
    Auto,
    Specified
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct GitProxyOptions
{
    public uint Version;
    public GitProxyType Type;
    public IntPtr Url;
    public IntPtr CredentialsCb;
    public IntPtr CertificateCheck;
    public IntPtr CbPayload;
}
```

}

is `libgit2sharp-ssh` not support working with proxy when using the `http/s` connection to git ?? (because working with libgit2sharp without the implementation of the ssh work with proxy well )

Comment: The function is define in   Network.cs file in LibGit2Sharp-ssh.core